# pandas: change the previous cell value of a column based on conditions in another column

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, multiple-columns

I have a Pandas dataset that looks like this: 
[dataset of words and their features](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jpCbt.png)

I would like to replace the "x "in "Gender" column with a condition that if a list of words like "Mädchen" is in the column "Words", "Neutral" should be put in the "Gender" column, in the previous word's row (which is a number).

So, for example, this:

```
Gender   Words

 x        10.
 x        Mädchen
```

Should become:

```
Gender   Words

Neutral   10.
 x        Mädchen
```

I have already tried `np.where` like this:

```
Food2_case["Gender"]= np.where(Food2_case.Words.isin(["Mädchen"]), (dropped_data.Words.str.contains('\d',regex= True) == 'A'), "x")
```

But I've got this error:

> ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes
>   (8000,) (275988,) ()

Comment: create an example dataframe with clearer details

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please take a moment to read about how to post pandas questions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following:

```
for index, row in Food2_case.iterrows():
    if(isinstance(row['Words'],str)):
        if('Mädchen' in row['Words']):
            Food2_case['Gender'][index-1] = 'Neutral'
```

If I understood your question correctly, it should work.

[EDIT]
If you want to check for other words other than `Mädchen`, you can do the following:

```
words_to_check = ['Mädchen', ...]

for index, row in Food2_case.iterrows():
    if(isinstance(row['Words'],str)):
        if(any((x in row['Words'] for x in words_to_check))):
            Food2_case['Gender'][index-1] = 'Neutral'
```

Comment: Thank you very much. this is working, but can I ask what I should do if I have a list of words and not just 'Mädchen' for which I need to do the same? thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 0):

```
# Create dataset
data = pd.DataFrame([[0, 0, 0], [10, "Madchen", 5]]).T
data.columns = ["Gender", "Words"]

# Shift one column of interest (take the value of previous row)
data.loc[:, "iswordin"] = data.Words.shift(-1)

# Do what you want to do
data.loc[data.iswordin.isin(["Madchen", "Girl", "boy", "..."]), "Gender"] = "Neutral"

# Now you can drop "iswordin" column which is no longer useful
```